# Adding suffix to a number using cultures

Tags: c#

I have a need to write dates in various languages.
Is it possible to write a date like 1st July -3rd October using cultures?

Cannot find a way to do it
Any suggestions?

EDIT

What I Mean is that if the choosen culture is English it should show
1st October 2010
if Spanish should show the equivalent for spanish note suffix(1st etc...)

Comment: why a -1, if you give a minus please add a comment why

Comment: What would you do if such a suffix doesn't exist in some languages? What if it's sometimes a prefix? Or a separate word? (btw, I didn't -1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you absolutely insist on doing this, here's the approach *I'd* take.

Define some simple interface with one method that takes a number and spits out a suffix. Like this:

```
interface INumberSuffixProvider
{
    string GetSuffix(int number);
}
```

Now, identify the languages you want to support. Figure out what their suffixes are. Write a class that implements `INumberSuffixProvider` for each of these languages (you may find it helpful to write a base class that provides a pretty standard implementation that will work similarly for most languages).

Finally, create a factory class to create an `INumberSuffixProvider` for a given culture string:

```
public class NumberSuffixProviderFactory
{
    public INumberSuffixProvider GetProvider(Language language)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case Language.English: return new EnglishNumberSuffixProvider();
            case Language.German: return new GermanNumberSuffixProvider();

            // etc., etc. -- this is just for illustration

            default: throw new ArgumentException("Unknown language.");
        }
    }
}
```

It's not the simplest solution, as it requires a bit of work on your part. But if you can determine what languages you want to support, at least once you have the basic structure in place (the above is just a sketch of an idea, really), actually putting this code to use should be quite easy.

For example:

```
string FormatDate(DateTime date)
{
    // These might be a static members.
    var language = _currentLanguage;
    var suffixProvider = _suffixProviderFactory.GetProvider(language);

    return string.Format(
        "{0}{1} {2:MMM} {3}",
        date.Day,
        suffixProvider.GetSuffix(date.Day),
        date,
        date.Year
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Shame the framework does not provide such a functionality.its up to us. thanks for very clear answer and suggestion

Comment: A nice clean implementation.

Comment: This solution still is not sufficient for other languages because the suffix also depends on the language context, e.g. in Spain. In this case it must be part of a translation resource. An option might be to just return a '.' by the Spain format provider and the translation must add the gender specific part. But other languages might have even more complex rules.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing built in to the .NET Framework for culture-specific formatting of ordinal numbers, as others have indicated.  And in any case, in many languages ordinals would not be used in dates (e.g. in Spanish, today's date is "9 de septiembre de 2010", not "9o septiembre 2010").

Other reasons why a general-purpose framework like .NET is never likely to include a culture-sensitive "GetOrdinalSuffix" method or similar include gender (1er, 1ère in French; 1o, 1a in Spanish, as well as the fact that there may be more than one form in a given language (1o/1º or 1a/1ª in Spanish) - which one you'd use might depend on the encoding you use when outputting the text.

> Any suggestions?

My suggestion would be don't do it.  Instead, explain to your users that it's complex because you would have to research every supported language, and persuade them to live without the suffixes.  Also explain to them that it's better to have dates formatted like every other application they use.

Answer (score 0):

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx):

```
string dateString = "5/1/2008 8:30:52 AM";
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(dateString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("F", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR")));
// Displays samedi 1 mars 2008 07:00:00
```

You can find DateTime.ToString() patterns [here](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not what I am looking for I need to Display 1st July 2008 - 2nd Aug 2010 etc  regardless of the Culture

Comment: @devnet247 - You should try writing your questions more clearly then, and actually explain what you want. This is what I would have interpreted it as asking too.

Comment: @devnet247: I suggest you rephrase your question, because you it's unclear as it is now: you say 'languages' and 'using cultures' and now you say it's regardless of culture. Is you problem displaying them or finding the intervals to display?

Comment: @Greg  + @Rox Sorry for not being clear. I will reedit the question

Answer (score 0):

Displaying "day-number month-name year" with month name in English is easy enough:

```
var dt = new DateTime(2010,9,9);
var str = dt.ToString("d MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvarientCulture);
```

gives:

```
9 September 2010
```

But there is nothing in [custom `DateTime` format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to give "st" etc. suffixes, so you'll need to do this yourself (untested):

```
var dt = get the date ...
var day = dt.Day;
var dayStr = day.ToString();
switch (day % 10) {
case 1:
   dayStr += "st";
   break;
case 2:
   dayStr += "nd";
   break;
default:
   dayStr += "th";
   break;
}

var result = String.Format({0} {1:MMMM yyyy}", dayStr, dt);
```

NB. This assumes English: different languages have different suffixes so you are going to need to build your own culture away code as [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo_members.aspx) doesn't provide for oridinal numbers. Wikipedia has some information on this (and note that word gender needs to be included) here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_indicator

Comment: Thanks Richard.But how do you handle different cultures?

Comment: @devnet247: was already updating on that. But your format is only really marginally applicable to English (one may pronounce a date as if written with ordinals, the suffixes are not normallly written, and it goes against style guides). that format certainly doesn't translate. When writing for a culture, use that culture's format.

Comment: @devnet247: you'll have to analyze the cases for each language and add an extra switch for the culture. Depending on the number of endings you might have a pattern or not.